# AngularJS authentication from remote server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to think on approach to do authentication with Angular and remote server. Usually what I do in local server, like what they did in MEAN.IO, check if has user and if it is I put it on the global window and that's how I know that user is authenticated.

for example in laravel:

```
  @if(Auth::check())
        <script>
            var user= [[[Auth::user()]]]
        </script>
        @endif
```

and it survive refresh because im check it at run time too.

but now the server is remotely and i have to do something like get request to some url /getUser. But thats not good since all the AngularJS
components will have to wait for the response to return causing inconsistencies and
development overhead.

So what I should do?

Comment: Try https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack - I think it has what you want out of the box

Comment: Yes i use this generator in the past and it does not have the answer.

Comment: You should bootstrap angular app manually after when you get user via GET /api/getUser. Should I explain more in answer?

Comment: Are you using the ui-router? Since in angular everything is asynchronous, you can throttle it very well. If you are using the ui router, you might be able to prevent the route changes until you have the response from the other server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "resolve" in order to avoid changing your current logic.

Define a Security service that performs the check let's say Security.getUser() and add it to the resolve of each route you need to secure. That way, your controller will be loaded only once the user is already checked. In case the server will return an authentication error, redirect to the login screen.

You can check out my slides from a secured angular talk I gave [goo.gl/kMvoFj](http://goo.gl/kMvoFj) 
or go over my github repository (It's still very raw, but the main idea is there) [ng-secure](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-secure), I think it might help you.

Comment: but i will need to send the request for every state that i want the user to be login?

Comment: No no, you won't have to. Just store the "user" the is returned in the service and in case it's already there return the user and don't execute the external request.